# Asp.net Mvc - EF: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute on Get ChangeTracker.Entries()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Have Problem when execute `SaveAllChangesAsync` in multi Browser Tab

error message:

```
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries() Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

---

Methods:

```
  #region SaveChanges
  
    public Task<int> SaveAllChangesAsync(bool invalidateCacheDependencies = true, Guid? auditUserId = null)
    {
        UpdateAuditFields();
        var result = SaveChangesAsync();
        if (!invalidateCacheDependencies) return result;
        var changedEntityNames = GetChangedEntityNames();
        new EFCacheServiceProvider().InvalidateCacheDependencies(changedEntityNames);

        return result;
    }

    #endregion

    #region UpdateAuditFields
    private void UpdateAuditFields()
    {

        var currentUserId = HttpContext.Current?.User == null ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User?.Identity.GetUserId());
        var auditDate = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedOn = auditDate;
                    entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                    entry.Entity.CreatorUserId = currentUserId;
                    entry.Entity.Action = AuditAction.Create;
                    entry.Entity.Version = 1;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                    entry.Entity.ModifierUserId = currentUserId;
                    entry.Entity.Version = ++entry.Entity.Version;
                    entry.Entity.Action = entry.Entity.IsDeleted ? AuditAction.SoftDelete : AuditAction.Update;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Detached:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Unchanged:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

  private string[] GetChangedEntityNames()
    {
        //error In this line
        return ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added ||
                        x.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                        x.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            .Select(x => ObjectContext.GetObjectType(x.Entity.GetType()).FullName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
    }
```

---

Stack Trace:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetEntityEntriesForDetectChanges(Dictionary`2 entityStore, List`1& entries)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetEntityEntriesForDetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()
   at Project.DataLayer.Context.BaseDbContext.GetChangedEntityNames() in C:\Users\Saman_Nima\source\repos\PanelV2\Project.DataLayer\Context\BaseDbContext.cs:line 147
   at Project.DataLayer.Context.BaseDbContext.SaveAllChangesAsync(Boolean invalidateCacheDependencies, Nullable`1 auditUserId) in C:\Users\Saman_Nima\source\repos\PanelV2\Project.DataLayer\Context\BaseDbContext.cs:line 98
   at Project.ServiceLayer.EFServices.Documents.CaseTollInvitationService.<SendInvitationAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Saman_Nima\source\repos\PanelV2\Project.ServiceLayer\EFServices\Documents\CaseTollInvitationService.cs:line 139
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Project.ServiceLayer.EFServices.Reports.ReportInvitationTajmieService.<GetReports>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Saman_Nima\source\repos\PanelV2\Project.ServiceLayer\EFServices\Reports\ReportInvitationTajmieService.cs:line 27
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Project.Web.Controllers.ReportInvitationTajmieController.<Report>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Saman_Nima\source\repos\PanelV2\Project.Web\Controllers\ReportInvitationTajmieController.cs:line 48
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing will likely be that you are modifying entities within a loop iterating through the change tracker. Instead, take snapshots of the applicable change state to iterate over:

```
var updatedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .ToList();
var insertedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .ToList();

foreach (var entity in insertedEntities)
{
    entity.CreatedOn = auditDate;
    entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
    entity.CreatorUserId = currentUserId;
    entity.Action = AuditAction.Create;
    entity.Version = 1;
}
foreach (var entity in updatedEntities)
{
    entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
    entity.ModifierUserId = currentUserId;
    entity.Version += 1
    entity.Action = entry.Entity.IsDeleted 
        ? AuditAction.SoftDelete 
        : AuditAction.Update;
}
```

If this is occurring with multiple browser then also check that your DbContext is scoped to the Request and not something like a Singleton. If you are using dependency injection to inject your DbContext, ensure that its lifetime scope is Per Web Request and not Singleton.

Code like "UpdateAuditFields" is something I would consider placing in an override of `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync` rather than a custom "SaveAllChanges" method unless you have a code inspection rule that checks for use of `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync` and flags those as should be using your custom method.

Comment: I used StructureMap and in injeted DbContext `For<ApplicationDbContext>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                               .Use(context => (ApplicationDbContext)context.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>());`.  is not Singleton